# In Hibernate while creating dynamic sql; how do i implement 1=1

Tags: sql, hibernate

I am using hibernate. I need to create query below. It is possible the  subContest is null in which case `subContest_id=:cont` should NOT be part of where clause. In conventional SQL when creating dynamic sql ; for such cases I used to do `subContest_id = subContest_id ;` BUT how do I achieve it in case below. Here If I try to `query.setParameter( "cont", "subContest_id " );` it will give exception as cont is supposed to be an id and not a string.

```
    Query query = getEntityManager().createQuery( "select * from Upload where moderated=:mod, subContest_id=:cont order by lastModifiedTime desc " );
    query.setParameter( "cont", subContest.getId() );
```

Comment: cant you use criteria API to create your dynamic query ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try using criteria query in hibernate

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Upload.class);
```

you can add your where clause as restrictions

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Upload.class)
    .add(Restrictions.eq("mode", value));
```

in your case you want to check null before adding restriction

```
if(subContest_id!=null){
        criteria.add(Expression.le("subContest_id",subContest_id));
    }
```

and finally order by can be done using this

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Upload.class)
    .addOrder( Order.desc("lastModifiedTime") );
```

please refer [here](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-criteria-examples/) for details on how to use criteria queries

Comment: I feel there should be a better way of doing it rather than so many if else.. like in dynamic sql we use to make it 1=1

Comment: @Deepak: *so many if else*? There is a single `if` in the above answer. You have to test if the parameter is null in one way or another.

Answer (score 1):

```
     Query query = null;
     if(cont != null){
        query = getEntityManager().createQuery( "select * from Upload where moderated=:mod, subContest_id=:cont order by lastModifiedTime desc " );
 query.setParameter( "cont", subContest.getId() );
 query.setParameter( "mod", moderated.getId() );
     } esle {
        query = getEntityManager().createQuery( "select * from Upload where moderated=:mod order by lastModifiedTime desc " );
 query.setParameter( "mod", moderated.getId() );
     }
```